# What is this character?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-desktop, telnet, special-characters

I'm running an Ubuntu machine and RDP'ing into a Windows 10 server. There's a .txt file on the server which when opened in Windows' text editor looks like this:

[image: this]

when I open a terminal and `type`the file it looks like this:

[image: this]

when I email the file to myself from within the VM, and open it in Ubuntu's text editor, it looks like this:

[image: this]

and when I `cat` the file on my Ubuntu machine it looks like this:

[image: this]

what character is this?

I ask because within the VM I'm pasting this line into a Telnet TCP socket connection, and the other side of this connection seems to be recognising this as some kind of terminating character. However, when I do the same from my Ubuntu host machine, the Telnet server doesn't seem to behave in the same way anymore, which makes me think it's some character specific to Windows, and Linux is either sending the wrong character or not sending one at all?

Comment: `02` and `03` would be ASCII "Start of text" and "End of text" escape codes. Most likely ignored by pretty much all modern systems. https://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php

Comment: A hex editor is your friend.  It looks like you tried to look at it every way but the only way.

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way to find out would be to load the file in a hex editor (binary editor), or to use a tool like `hd` or `hexdump -C` or `xxd`, to look at the byte values of those characters.

Though, your screenshot shows the GTK-based text editor telling you that the characters are U+0002 and U+0003 – those are "decoded" Unicode codepoints that the editor deals in, not the "raw" bytes in the file, but you can still look them up in a site such as codepoints.net which says:

| Codepoint number | Name in Unicode | Byte representation in UTF-8 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U+0002 | Start of Text | 0x02 |
| U+0003 | End of Text | 0x03 |

All Unicode codepoints below U+007F correspond 1:1 to positions in the ASCII table, and their UTF-8 representations are also identical to those in ASCII.

So they're "not quite characters" from the [C0 control code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) range – they do not have a standard visual representation, as their purpose is to act as delimiters in machine-read files, not in human-read text. Some programs might show them as "STX" and "ETX" (according to their ASCII names) or as "^B" and "^C" (as they also correspond to Ctrl- keys in terminals); some programs might not show them at all.

The Windows console, with its MS-DOS roots, displays such characters the way they would have looked in the [IBM PC codepages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) – when bytes 0x02 and 0x03 were put directly in video RAM, the PC would show `☻` and `♥` accordingly.